# Is it possible to reduce no of markers in a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a fitted distribution curve where I would like to reduce no. of markers.

Can anyone suggest tricks to do that?

Comment: Show the code you already have. One idea would be to draw the fit line using less points, that's the third parameter in numpy.linspace if that's what you're using.

Comment: Also try to explain better what you have and what you want to achieve. The number of _what_ markers you want to reduce?

Comment: I m fitting a normal distribution for a histogram from a data. So, once I fit it I want to see markers as well as line. high density to markers is what I would like to reduce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`plot`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot) command has an argument `markevery`.

> `markevery`    [None | int | length-2 tuple of int | slice | list/array of int | float | length-2 tuple of float]

This is a bit cryptic, but there is [an example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/markevery_demo.html) on the matplotlib page, showing different ways to use this argument.

Quoting from the example's text:

> Integer arguments are fairly intuitive.  e.g. `markevery`=5 will plot every
>   5th marker starting from the first data point.
>   Float arguments allow markers to be spaced at approximately equal distances
>   along the line.  The theoretical distance along the line between markers is
>   determined by multiplying the display-coordinate distance of the axes
>   bounding-box diagonal by the value of `markevery`.  The data points closest
>   to the theoretical distances will be shown.

So for a simple example case, use

```
plt.plot(x,y, marker="o", markevery=5)
```

to plot every 5th marker only.